# 'a' is missing when printing alphabet backwards with lists

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to print the alphabet backwards using linked lists but I can't get the 'a' to show up. For some reason it skips it and I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        char s[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        node *head;
        node *temp;
        node *current;

        head = new node;          // create the head of the linked list
        head->data = s[25];
        head->next = NULL;
        temp = head;   // get ready for the loop - save the head in temp - you are         going to change temp in the loop

        for(size_t i = 25; i >= 1; i--)      // create the rest of the linked list
        {
            current = new node;    // make a new node
            current->data = s[i];  // set it's data member
            current->next = NULL;
            temp->next = current;  // point to the new node
            temp = current;        // make temp point to current node (for next         time through)
        }

        node *ptr = head;    // set a ptr to head, then you are going to "increment"         the pointer

        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            cout << ptr->data; // print out the linked list
            ptr = ptr->next;   // increment the linked list
        }

        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

does anyone know why it's happening? I think something is wrong in my for loop. Thank you!

Comment: It's happening because you committed an "off by one" bug somewhere. It would be good for you to spend all the time needed to find this by yourself. Single-step through the code with a debugger, or add print statements to show the states of variabes at every step. Good luck.

Comment: Note that to use a linked list to print the alphabet backwards is very easy. Step through the string from left to right, and for each letter, **push** a new node onto the stack, containing that letter. Then pop all the node from the stack one by one and print each node's letter.

Comment: `for(size_t i = 25; i >= 1 /* should be 0 not 1! */ ; i--)` Array indices start at `0` in [tag:c] and [tag:c++]!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are leaving out the case `i=0` from your for loop.

Change your `for` loop to this:

```
    size_t i = 25; // 'z' was already added
    do
    {
        --i;
        current = new node;    // make a new node
        current->data = s[i];  // set it's data member
        current->next = NULL;
        temp->next = current;  // point to the new node
        temp = current;        // make temp point to current node (for next         time through)
    } while ( i != 0 );
```

The reason you can't simply do `for(size_t i = 25; i >= 0; i--)` is because `i` is unsigned, and so it will always be the case that `i >= 0` and thus the loop will never terminate, or more likely you will get a segmentation fault.

Comment: I fixed my for loop to for(int i = strlen(s) - 2; i >= 0; i--) and it fixed the problem. I needed to add the = next to >. When I used 0 and used > instead of >= it was erroring. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(size_t i = 25; i >= 0; i--)
```

'a' is the index 0 in your string, you never get to index 0.

Comment: Could you explain why this for loop is necessary and why OP's for loop was not working correctly in your answer?